# Polymorphism and Java collections

Tags: java, interface

I have an Interface Fruit and classes that implement the Interface as follows:

```
Apple implements Fruit
Banana implements Fruit
```

I have a legacy method that works off the Interface like

```
public String checkFruitColor(List<Fruit> fruit)
{
 ....
 ....
 return fruit.getColor();
}
```

I am trying to pass in List, List

**The issue is that the method is not accepting a list of the Apple, Manago. It is asking for an object of Type Fruit.**

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've already done it. What's the problem?

Comment: I think that's exactly what you did above, nice job! :D

Comment: Hi Guys, Let me edit the question and explain the problem again

Comment: Can you give us the full definition of the `Fruit` interface?

Comment: What's the issue? Is it that `Fruit` has no `getColor` method?

Comment: No problem. Should work as is.

Comment: It will works. Is this your real code what you write?

Comment: When you say "It is asking for an object of Type Fruit." what is the exact compiler error message you get?

Comment: I think it would help if you provided a short but complete sample app that contains the error you're seeing. We're all trying to extrapolate that app from the fragments you've shown, but the app we're extrapolating compiles and runs.

Comment: I would also suggest you to check the fully qualified names (package.ClassName) of the two Fruits (one in the method signature and another implemented by the Apple/Banana).

Comment: @yshavit I agree. I'll be able to do it tomorrow. A big thank you to all those who have replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **actual** question seems to be:

You have

```
interface Fruit
class Apple implements Fruit
class Banana implements Fruit
```

Then you have a method

```
public String checkFruitColor(List<Fruit> fruit)
```

And you have

```
List<Apple> apples = //something
List<Banana> bananas = //something
```

Now, you have made the (common) assumption and `List<Apple>` is a subclass of `List<Fruit>` because `Apple` is a subclass of `Fruit`.

But, that means we could do

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
List<Fruit> fruits = apples //all good as List<Apple> is a subclass of List<Fruit>
fruits.add(new Banana()); //we can add a Banana to a List<Fruit>
final Apple apple = apples.get(0); //a List<Apple> will always have apples.
```

OOPS!!

So, in fact, a `List<Apple>` is not related to a `List<Fruit>` - as far as the compiler is concerned they are completely different. Put in technical terms, `List` is invariant in its type.

In order to make what you have work, you need to tell the compiler that you want a `List` of some subtype of `Fruit` but you don't care what.

```
public String checkFruitColor(List<? extends Fruit> fruit)
```

This will allow you to pass your `List<Apple>` to `checkFruitColor` and access the items as instances of `Fruit`.

What you cannot do is `add()` to the list as you do not know what the type of the `List` is.

Comment: @John my pleasure. But a point for the future would be to triple check your question before posting. Posting the wrong question is waste of your time, and you have also wasted the time of at least 4 other people.

Comment: Yes I am really sorry and will be more careful in future.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code example to show why polymorphism wouldn't work on Collections can be applied to arrays, right? So `Apple[] apples = new Apple[0];  Fruit[] fruit = apples; // works because Apple extends Fruit; fruit[0] = new Banana(); final Apple apple = apples[0];` Why would this be OK but your example not? It's just not logical to allow this for arrays but not for collections, even though the outcome (thinking that apples[0] is an Apple but is in fact a Banana) would be exactly the same. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If my previous comment stands, then I think it's stupid to not allow this for Collections but to still allow it for arrays, since there isn't any logical difference.

Comment: It would throw an `ArrayStoreException`. It's specifically this nasty behaviour that type invariant generics prevent - they turn a runtime error into a compile time one. @klaar

Comment: I understand that having a compile time error is (much more) preferable to having a runtime error. Still, I lament the fact that they somewhat crippled the advantages of polymorphism in collections. If I want to just receive a Collection of any type extending a supertype, it's necessary to use `Collection<? extends Super>` (or an equivalent Generic type) as the type, instead of just using `Collection<Super>`. Using arrays, I could have just typed `Super[]`, so why can't I for Collections? Because they want to catch a silly runtime error during compile time? Bleh.

Comment: I honestly don't understand your suggestion @klaar. A `Collection<Apple>` simply **not** a `Collection<Fruit>` because one can `add(banana)` to a `Collection<Fruit>`. There is no alternative to the current implementation. The fact that arrays are fundamentally broken is a problem not a solution.

Comment: A collection of apples isn't a collection of fruit indeed, but I should be able to add that collection to another collection of fruit. I should be able to just ask for a collection of any fruit if I only need to use those items as fruit and nothing more specific. I agree about the problem with arrays, but that's the risk involved in using polymorphism: casting from a less to a more specifc Class is something that should be done very carefully, including masking a collection or array to a more generic class and then attempting to use it as a more specific class again without consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already have a `getColor()`in your Fruit interface.
When a class implements an interface it agrees to the *contract* of the interface, meaning that it must provide an implementation for all methods in that interface.

Thus, both Apple and Banana will have their own implementation of `getColor()` and return a correct value. From here on you can just pass an Apple or Banana instance to your check method, since they are both classed as Fruit-instances since they implement Fruit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of Apple or Banana to your method checkFruitColor(Fruit fruit).

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
apple.setColor("Red");
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
fruits.add(apple);
checkFruitColor(fruits);
```

Here you cannot directly call fruit.getColor(). You need to iterate through the list and invoke getter for each object.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a compilation error. I'll need to get back to you on the error as I don't have access to my machine.

Comment: @John, check the signature of Fruit, see whether it is 'public interface Fruit'. Also cross check whether you have imported the correct Fruit interface in the calling class.

Comment: I just remembered that in my actual problem. I was dealing with Lists. Please see the edit I have made to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem in this, you have implemented it corrrectly:-

```
public String checkFruitColor(Fruit fruit)
{
 return fruit.getColor();
}
```

Fruit type in parameter restricts the accepted parameter type in the checkFruitColor() function to fruits. Which is implemented by Apple and Banana class, Hence you can pass both Apple and Banana object to it.

You can also pass mango if

```
Mango implements Fruit
```

If you want to get explicitly the apple object again in the method you can do this by

```
public String checkFruitColor(Fruit fruit)
    {
      Apple apple=(Apple)fruit; //casting the fruit to apple, make sure the object passed is apple only
      return apple.getColor();
    }
```

But if all fruits have getColor() method, then why do this, your approach is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but it could have to do with the fact that a variable of type `List<Apple>` is not valid when passed to a function expecting `List<Fruit>`.  This is due to the way Java handles generics.  The method would have to have been defined as expecting a variable of type `List<? extends Fruit>` and then it would work.  See this question: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)